# Retrieving multiple information for new activity

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

I'm new to Android developing programming. I'm trying to pass through multiple information from my starting activity to a new activity and i can't figure out how to retrieve all of the values.

My MainActivity `buttonSend` event code is this:

```
public void sendInformation (View view) {

    Intent intent = new Intent(this, DisplayInformation.class);
    EditText toText = (EditText) findViewById (R.id.toText);                //Finds the control 'toText' in the form and gets it by ID
    EditText fromText = (EditText) findViewById (R.id.fromText);            //Finds the control 'fromText' in the form and gets it by ID
    EditText messageText = (EditText) findViewById (R.id.messageText);      //Finds the control 'messageText' in the form and gets it by ID
    EditText subjectText = (EditText) findViewById (R.id.subjectText);      //Finds the control 'subjectText' in the form and gets it by ID

    String toMessage = toText.getText().toString();                         //Gets the text that you enter for the 'To'Field
    String fromMessage = fromText.getText().toString();                     //Gets the text that you enter for the 'From' field
    String messageMessage = messageText.getText().toString();               //Gets the text that you enter for the 'Message' field
    String subjectMessage = subjectText.getText().toString();               //Gets the text that you enter for the 'Subject' field

    intent.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE, toMessage);
    intent.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE, fromMessage);
    intent.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE, messageMessage);
    intent.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE, subjectMessage);

    startActivity(intent);
}
```

`EXTRA_MESSAGE` is defined as `public final static String EXTRA_MESSAGE = "com.example.Fun.MESSAGE";` I don't really know what this does to be honest the tutorial just told me to include it.

In my second activity page i have this code for the `onCreate` instance:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_display_information);

    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment()).commit();
    }

    Intent intent = getIntent();
    String toMessage = intent.getStringExtra(MainActivity.EXTRA_MESSAGE);
    String fromMessage = intent.getStringExtra(MainActivity.EXTRA_MESSAGE);
    String subjectMessage = intent.getStringExtra(MainActivity.EXTRA_MESSAGE);
    String messageMessage = intent.getStringExtra(MainActivity.EXTRA_MESSAGE);

    TextView toMessagetextView = new TextView(this);
    toMessagetextView.setTextSize(40);
    toMessagetextView.setText(toMessage);

    TextView fromMessagetextView = new TextView(this);
    fromMessagetextView.setTextSize(40);
    fromMessagetextView.setText(fromMessage);

    TextView subjectMessagetextView = new TextView(this);
    subjectMessagetextView.setTextSize(40);
    subjectMessagetextView.setText(subjectMessage);

    TextView messageMessagetextView = new TextView(this);
    messageMessagetextView.setTextSize(40);
    messageMessagetextView.setText(messageMessage);



    setContentView(toMessagetextView);
    setContentView(fromMessagetextView);
    setContentView(subjectMessagetextView);
    setContentView(messageMessagetextView);



}
```

When I go to run my app it errors out and shuts down.

*Also if anybody could tell me how to put the `TextView` in the `fragment.xml` file for the second activity it would be greatly appreciated. I know how to declare the `id` and what not but i don't know to use it with retrieving data from another activity yet.

Thank you in advance for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using same key `EXTRA_MESSAGE` for all extra values. Intent stores values like Map.

So here you are loosing all the value other than `subjectMessage`, because it was added at last.

You have to use different keys for each values. like

```
public final static String EXTRA_MESSAGE_TO = "com.example.Fun.MESSAGE_TO";
public final static String EXTRA_MESSAGE_FROM = "com.example.Fun.MESSAGE_FROM";
public final static String EXTRA_MESSAGE_SUBJECT = "com.example.Fun.MESSAGE_SUBJECT";
public final static String EXTRA_MESSAGE = "com.example.Fun.MESSAGE";
```

Comment: So I would declare another `global variable` just with another name and assign it to one of my 4 `messages`?

Comment: Yes. Updated the answer look over

Comment: Ok thank, you, so is my updated method more correct now?